# 'int' object is not subscriptable using type()

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.7, indentation

I cannot figure out why I am getting this error:
if type(location[choice[c]]) == int and location[choice[c]] % 3 == 0:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

I do not understand what the error means.

My code:

```
candy = ["Hi-Chew",10,200, 'Gummy bear',8,200, 'skittles',11,200, 'Mint',13,200, 
'Cadbury',10,200,]

bakedGood= ['Bread (Whole Wheat)',10,200, 'White bread',10,200, 'Baguette',15,200, 'Cheese 
Bread',12,200, 'sausage bun',13,200]

meat = ['Chicken nuggets (12 peices)',10,200, 'BBQ  wings (6 pc)',15,200, 'Pizza meat-eater (10 
cm radius)',40,200, 'Cheeseburger',15,200, 'Chicken Breast',25,200] 

savouryVeg = ['pizza (veg)',45,200, 'Salad',20,200, 'Fries',10,200,'veg 
burger',20,200,'Naan',12,200]

bakedSw = ['Strawberry cake',50,50, 'Chocolate cake',50,50, 'Chocolate cupcake',15,100,'Glazed 
donut',10,200, 'Chocolate donut',10,200,]

location = [candy,bakedGood,meat,savouryVeg,bakedSw]

categories = ['Candy', 'Baked Goods', 'Meat', 'Veg', 'Baked sweets']

def menu ():
    order = ''
    for i in range (1,len(categories)):
            print(str(i+1)+".", categories[i])
    choice = int(input("Choose a category by typing the number beside the categories name."))
    print("Items in this list are")
    print("%-10s%-17s"%('Item name', 'Price'))
    for c in range (len(location[choice])):
            if type(location[choice[c]]) == int and location[choice[c]] % 3 == 0:
                    print("%-10s%-17s"%(location[choice[c]], location[choice[c+1]]))
```

Comment: `choice` is an integer.  It makes no sense to say `choice[c]`.  Perhaps you meant `categories[c]`?

Comment: `choice` is an `int`, what do you expect `choice[c]` to do?

Comment: `location[choice[c]] -> location[choice][c]`

Comment: Why are you using two lists instead of a dictionary that maps the category names to the items in the categories?

Comment: Also, lists should generally be uniform data. You should be using a list of tuples or a list of dictionaries to group the item names with their corresponding data.

Answer (score 0):

Choice itself is an int :

```
    choice = int(input("Choose a category by typing the number beside the categories name."))
```

choice[c] is breaking because it looks like you're doing 1[1].

You likely want to use slicing here:

```
location[::c]
```

for example